# How can I stop execution of other code until thread concludes?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

[PROBLEM]
How can I stop execution of other code until thread concludes ?.

In practical terms, I have an wxpython. (gui + business logic).
    gui - gui.py
    business logic :
    a) main.py 
    b) specific.py

**[gui.py]**

```
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World", size=(300,200))
def testcaseandLog(event):
        print "begin"
        import sys
        from main import mainPyBeginTest
        mainPyBeginTest()    
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
addButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Run", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, testcaseandLog, addButton)
top.SetSizer(sizer)
top.SetFocus()
top.Center()
top.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

**[main.py]**

```
def mainPyBeginTest():
        print "main py"
        import specific
```

**[specific.py]**

```
def testMethod():
        import wx
        appSecond = wx.App(redirect=False)
        topSecond = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World", size=(300,200))
        import wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo as PBI
        message = "Please wait, working..."
        busy = PBI.PyBusyInfo(message, parent=topSecond, title="processing")
        wx.Yield()
        for indx in xrange(5):
            wx.MilliSleep(1000)
        del busy
        topSecond.Show(True)
        topSecond.Destroy()
        appSecond.ExitMainLoop()
        appSecond.MainLoop()
def afterMethod():
     import threading
     t = threading.Thread(target=testMethod)
     t.setDaemon(1)
     t.start()
     import time
     time.sleep(10)
afterMethod()
def after():
    print "why is this gettting executed before testMethod"
after()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to [join your thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

```
t = threading.Thread(target=testMethod)
t.setDaemon(1)
t.start()
t.join()  # This will cause the main thread to block until the 't' thread completes.
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (by adding the line "t.join()" in specific.py). In the same time, the testMethod() is not executed anymore. I will keep digging ...